# Can you help me with the $x^{\ln(x)-1}\ln(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Recently, I tried to solve $\displaystyle\int x^{\ln(x)-1}\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx$ then I was stuck on this part (but not on the substitution).

My stuck was when I saw in the calculator, that it does this:

> $$\displaystyle\int x^{\ln(x)-1}\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
> Prepare for Substitution:
> $$\int\frac{1}{x}\cdot e^{\ln^2(x)}\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

My question is, how $x^{\ln(x)-1}\ln(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot e^{\ln^2(x)}\ln(x)=\dfrac{e^{\ln^2(x)}\ln(x)}{x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned} \because x^{\ln x-1} = & \frac{x^{\ln x}}{x} \\
= & \frac{e^{\ln \left(x^{\ln x}\right)}}{x} \\
= & \frac{e^{\ln x(\ln x)}}{x} \\
= & \frac{e^{\ln ^2 x}}{x}\\ \therefore  x^{\ln x-1} \ln x=&\frac{e^{\ln ^2 x} \ln x}{x}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your demonstration and now I understand.

Comment: Glad to know that it helps!

Answer (score 4):

We know that (for $x>0$)
$$
x = e^{\ln(x)}
$$
so
$$\begin{align*}
x^{\ln(x)-1}
&= e^{\ln ( x^{\ln(x)-1})}\\
&= e^{(\ln(x) - 1) \ln(x)}\\
&= e^{\ln^2(x) - \ln(x)}\\
&= e^{\ln^2(x)} e^{-\ln(x)}\\
&= \frac{1}{e^{\ln(x)}} e^{\ln^2(x)} \\
&= \frac 1 x e^{\ln^2(x)}
\end{align*}$$

- The second equality uses the rule $\ln(x^r) = r \ln(x)$
- The third equality is just distribution
- The fourth equality uses the rule $a^{b+c} = a^b \cdot a^c$
- The fifth equality uses the rule $a^{-b} = 1/a^b$
- The final equality uses the special rule mentioned, $x = e^{\ln(x)}$

Comment: FYI, rather than starting with your $x^{\ln(x)-1}=e^{\ln ( x^{\ln(x)-1})}$, I believe a bit simpler way to handle it instead is to note that $x^{\ln(x)-1}=(x^{\ln(x)})(x^{-1})=\left((e^{\ln(x)})^{\ln(x)}\right)(x^{-1})=\frac{1}{x}e^{\ln^2(x)}$.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration with the information you provided me so I can understand of it.